# 502 Bad Gateway error with nginx and unicorn

Tags: nginx, unicorn

I have nginx 1.4.1 and unicorn set up on centos  - I am getting a 502 Bad Gateway error and my nginx logs shows this:

```
1 connect() to unix:/tmp/unicorn.pantry.sock failed (2: No such file or directory)
while connecting to upstream, client: 192.168.1.192, server: , request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", 
upstream: "http://unix:/tmp/unicorn.pantry.sock:/", host: "192.168.1.30"
```

There is no /tmp/unicorn.pantry.sock file or directory. I am thinking that it might be a permission error and therefore the file can't be written if so who requires what permission - I have also read that I can create a  tcp client

Also I don't understand where the 192.168.1.192 comes from

I just want to make it work How can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I figured this out. I had unicorn.sock in my shared directory so I needed to point unix: to it

Comment: How do you mean you had to point unix to it? I am curious as to how you fixed this

Comment: same. I've added the unix:/path/to/sock and it still doesn't work. I'm still getting bad gateway

Comment: @Noobie1, were you able to figure this out? I'm getting the same error

Comment: how to find where is my sock file